# Opening programs in applescript using "Choose file"

Tags: macos, web-applications, applescript

I have an application were the user chooses an application to send a command to. but I keep getting an error message when I run it.

```
set setApp to choose file
tell application [setApp]
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special dialog for choosing an application:

```
set theApp to choose application

tell theApp to activate
```